# Which one is more effective extra param in lambda or overloading a method?

Tags: java, lambda, overloading

I have written a lambda and I am not able to make a decision whether to simplify the lambda or to make an extra method in the code. So, here's the scenario -

MyIterator

```
public Iterator<DTO> getIterator(final String someFilter) {
    return new PageIterator<>(page -> getSomething(page, someFilter), 1);
}
```

getSomething

```
 public List<DTO> getSomething(final int pageNumber, final String someFilter) {
    return getSomething(pageNumber, DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE, someFilter);
}
```

overloaded getSomething

```
public List<DTO> getSomething(final int pageNumber, final int pageSize, final String someFilter) { 
 //Returns List<DTO>
 }
```

I can actually call the overloaded getSomething directly from the getIterator by adding DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE to the parameter and can get rid of the overloading.

The question is - 
which way is better -to simplify lambda or not to overload method?

Just asking for opinions regarding the performance and simplicity of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with lambdas. You're asking if helper overloads with fewer parameters is a good thing.
Answer: Yes.

It is the Java way of define default parameters, and the Java Runtime Library does it all over the place.

Examples:

```
Integer.parseInt(String s) // default: radix = 10
Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)

string.substring(int beginIndex) // default: endIndex = string.length()
string.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification !